# explanation on how unapply method works in Scala

Tags: scala

Have I understood the flow correctly? Consider followig code

```
class Employee(val firstName: String, val middleName: Option[String], val lastName: String)

object Tokenizer {
  def unapply(x: Employee) = Some(x.firstName, x.lastName)
}

val e = new Employee("Kurt", None, "Vonnegut") 
val result = e match {
  case Tokenizer(c, d) ⇒ "c: %s, d: %s".format(c, d)
  case _ ⇒ "Not found"
}
```

Am I correct that `e` will be passed to `Tokenizer.unapply(x:Employee)` and the result of `Some()` is assigned to `(c,d)`? From the looks of the code, it seems that we are calling `Tokenizer(c,d)` but no `apply` or `unapply` method is defined with signature simialar to `Tokenizer(c,d)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have understood it correctly. `unapply` can be a bit mind bending, because when you see it in a `case`, you write its *return type* instead of the *argument type*. The signature of `Tokenizer.unapply` is `Employee => Some[(String, String)]`. The part that corresponds to `case Tokenizer(c, d)` is the return type.

However, I have a couple of (very small) nits to pick. You should give types to all public methods, because you can end up inferring too specific a type (it shows up here by inferring `Some` instead of `Option`), and then changing your code (in this case, maybe making it so `Tokenizer.unapply` can fail with `None`) changes its interface. However, if you expect that you *won't* change `Tokenizer` to be able to fail, there's no need to incur a boxing penalty by returning an `Option`. You can instead do

```
// Don't worry if you don't understand this yet. You can ignore this trick and come back to it much later
// Also: I think this only works on Scala 2.12
final case class Box[+T](t: T) extends AnyVal {
  def isEmpty = false
  def get = t
}
object Tokenizer {
  def unapply(e: Employee): Box[(String, String)] = Box((e.firstName, e.lastName))
}
// Incurs no boxing penalty, but now you can't change it to allow failure without changing the interface
```

Final nit: it is bad style to call a function that expects a tuple without double parens. Don't write `Some(a, b)`; write `Some((a, b))`. It's a bit ugly, but the first can be ambiguous, and that's worse.

Comment: So unapply will work even if it returns something other than option. Are `get` and `isEmpty` a necessary interface for something unapply returns?

Comment: `unapply` can also return a `Boolean` (in which case there are no values extracted). Otherwise, yes, I think `isEmpty` and `get` are all that matter.

Answer (score 0):

An object with an `unapply` method is an extractor object. It does the inverse of the `apply` method by extracting the individual values that were passed to `apply`. So in the above example `result` will contain the tuple `("Kurt", "Vonnegut")`.

Note that you could also use an assignment instead of pattern matching here:

```
$ val Tokenizer(emp) = e
emp: (String, String) = ("Kurt", "Vonnegut")
```